# Appsflyer deeplink не открывает приложение из браузера и webview других приложений

Tags: android, браузер, webview, deeplink

У меня есть deeplink созданный на appsflyer. Deeplink находится на сайте и должен по клику на кнопку открывать приложение на телефоне, но открывается Google Play вместо приложения. В AndroidManifest есть фильтр обрабатывающий ссылки. Deeplink работает если его открывать из Chrome или например из чата телеграмма.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все правильно настроено, раз работает в Chrome.

Проблема либо во встроенном браузере, либо в том, как вы тестируете. Обратите внимание на данный [пункт](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/ru/articles/360014821438#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-onelink-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) в документации OneLink:

> Могут ли настраиваемые ссылки OneLink открывать приложение из браузера?

> Да, но обратите внимание, что универсальные ссылки iOS и Android App Links работают только при клике по ним (например, при клике по ссылке на веб-странице или в электронном сообщении). Если вставить ссылку в адресную строку браузера, запуска приложения не происходит.Чтобы протестировать ссылки, нажимайте их, а не копируйте в адресную строку браузера.